# Vector : t A n = t A (n+0)?

Tags: coq

I want trivial lemma below.

```
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.

Lemma one (A:Type)(n:nat): t A n = t A (n+0).
Proof.
induction n. reflexivity.
Abort.
```

How do I simplify (n+0) to n ?

Comment: This lemma is in the Standard Library as `plus_n_O`.  The whole proof  of `Lemma one` is `rewrite <- plus_n_O; reflexivity.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to prove an equality between complex structures it can often be useful to use the `f_equal` tactic which will ask to prove that the subterms are equal. For instance here it turns `t A n = t A (n+0)` into `n = n + 0`.
Once you have this, you can use the very useful `lia` tactic to deal with equalities on natural numbers.

```
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.
From Coq Require Import Lia.

Lemma one (A:Type)(n:nat): t A n = t A (n+0).
Proof.
  f_equal. lia.
Qed.
```

(Notice that you have to require the `Lia` module to use `lia`.)

In some cases you will not be proving an equality directly so it might be useful to replace `n+0` with `n`:

```
Lemma one (A:Type)(n:nat): t A n = t A (n+0).
Proof.
  (* f_equal. lia. *)
  replace (n + 0) with n by lia.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```